# pandas dataframe return boolean if the column value is NaN

Tags: pandas

I have Pandas DataFrame with multiple columns, i wanted to check if the specific column value is NaN, if Yes, i need to return boolean (True or False).

I tried

```
pandas_df['col1'].isnull()
```

But it returns all the rows with index and boolean value.

Comment: @jezrael, the expected output is just boolean True or False

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC you need `.any()` to check if there is any null values:

```
pandas_df.col1.isnull().any()
```

Comment: One more option is `pandas_df.col1.hasnans` but not recommended. `any()` is more reliable

Answer (score 2):

For return boolean scalar use [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) - test if at least one `NaN` (at least one `True`) per column:

```
pandas_df['col1'].isnull().any()
```

If need test if all valeus are `NaN`s use [`Series.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html):

```
pandas_df['col1'].isnull().all()
```

---

```
pandas_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,np.nan],
                          'col2':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

print (pandas_df['col1'].isnull().any())
True

print (pandas_df['col2'].isnull().all())
True
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `isna()`. This is [identical](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0409521665bd436a10aea7e06336066bf07ff057/pandas/core/dtypes/missing.py#L109) to `isnull()`

[`df.isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) will detect missing values on the whole dataframe.

---

```
   age       born    name        toy
0  5.0        NaT  Alfred       None
1  6.0 1939-05-27  Batman  Batmobile
2  NaN 1940-04-25              Joker
```

Calling `df.isna()` will return `True` on missing values (the trio `NaN`, `NaT` and `None`):

```
     age   born   name    toy
0  False   True  False   True
1  False  False  False  False
2   True  False  False  False
```